# GUI problems in tkinter, variable not executed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

For some reason the defined variable more_universities is not executing and no error is being shown by python, so this is actually giving me problems in the moment I try to take the GUI any further.

This code will later be useful for obtaining data and writing files with it (I have not taken it to that point yet)

```html
#Importing all modules

import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

#This is the text we want to display

def texto():
    greets = ("Gracias por postularse " + str(Name) + "\n ")
    contact1 = ("Lo contactaremos a su correo electronico: " + str(Email) + "\n ")
    contact2 = ("En caso de no ser posible o no ver respuesta su numero de telefono: " + str(Phone) + " sera contactado \n ")
    contact3 = ("Su salario deseado es: " + str(Salary) + " y sera tomado en consideracion \n ")
    text = greets + contact1 + contact2 + contact3 
    return text

#Function created to active the text once the information is filled

def display_information():
    #Displaying the text in this same window
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Aplicacion sometida")
    greet = tk.Label(window, text = "A quien corresponda: ")
    greet.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    Result = tk.Label(window, text = texto())
    Result.grid(row = 1 ,column = 1)
    window.mainloop()

#Get values of the entries

def get_values():
    #Strings
    global Name
    global Email
    global Phone
    global Salary
    global ID
    Name = String1.get()
    Email = String2.get()
    Phone = String3.get()
    Salary = String4.get()
    #Booleans
    global licencia 
    global carnet 
    global universidad 
    global identificacion 
    licencia = boolean1.get()
    carnet = boolean2.get()
    universidad = boolean3.get()
    identificacion = boolean4.get()
    university()

#If university has been achieved 

def university():

    #If the person has university studies

    if universidad == True: 

        #Creation of the window

        master = tk.Tk()
        master.title("Informacion Universitaria")

        #Labels of the university

        myfont = font.Font(size = 15)
        Title = tk.Label(master, text = "LUNCHEVA S.A")
        Title.config(fg = 'green')
        Title['font'] = myfont
        Title.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        greeting = tk.Label(master, text = "Por favor introduzca la informacion solicitada: ")
        greeting.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        universidad2 = tk.Label(master, text = "Universidad a la cual asistio:")
        universidad2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        estudios = tk.Label(master, text = "Area en la cual realizo sus estudios:")
        estudios.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        pais = tk.Label(master, text = "Pais en el cual realizo estos estudios:")
        pais.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        mas = tk.Label(master, text = "En caso de poseer mas de un titulo universitario")
        mas.grid(row = 5, column = 2)

        mas2 = tk.Label(master, text = "Haga click a continuacion")
        mas2.grid(row = 6, column = 2)

        #String values for the entries 

        String_1 = tk.StringVar(master)
        String_2 = tk.StringVar(master)
        String_3 = tk.StringVar(master)

        #Entries of the university 

        u1 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = String_1, width = 30)
        u1.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        u2 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = String_2, width = 30)
        u2.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        u3 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = String_3, width = 30)
        u3.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

        #Boolean value for university 

        boolean_1 = tk.BooleanVar(master)

        #Checkbuttons for the boolean value in university 
        #In case the subject has more than university title 

        titulo = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Poseo mas de un titulo", variable = boolean_1)
        titulo.grid(row = 7, column = 2)

        #In order to obtain the information of this window 

        def get_values_university(): 
            #Strings 
            global u1
            global u2
            global u3
            u1 = String_1.get()
            u2 = String_2.get()
            u3 = String_3.get()
            #Booleans 
            global titulo
            titulo = boolean_1.get()

        #Obtaining the information 

        get_values_university()

        # Submit button

        titulo_21 = tk.Button(master, text = "Agregar mas informacion", fg = 'green',activebackground = "green", activeforeground = "green", command= more_universities())
        titulo_21.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

        submit2 = tk.Button(master, text = "Enviar", fg = 'green',activebackground = "green", activeforeground = "green", command= get_values_university())
        submit2.grid(row = 99, column = 99)

        master.mainloop()

#To get the values of the university if it has been achieved 

def more_universities():

    if titulo == True: 

        #Destroying the previous window 

        master.destroy()

        #Creation of the window

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Informacion Universitaria")

        #Labels of the university

        myfont = font.Font(size = 15)
        Title = tk.Label(root, text = "LUNCHEVA S.A")
        Title.config(fg = 'green')
        Title['font'] = myfont
        Title.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        greetingg = tk.Label(root, text = "Por favor introduzca la informacion solicitada: ")
        greetingg.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        universidad2g = tk.Label(root, text = "Universidad a la cual asistio:")
        universidad2g.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        estudiosg = tk.Label(root, text = "Area en la cual realizo sus estudios:")
        estudiosg.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        paisg = tk.Label(root, text = "Pais en el cual realizo estos estudios:")
        paisg.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        masg = tk.Label(root, text = "En caso de poseer mas de un titulo universitario")
        masg.grid(row = 5, column = 2)

        mas2g = tk.Label(root, text = "Haga click a continuacion")
        mas2g.grid(row = 6, column = 2)

        saludo2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Segundo titulo universitario:")
        saludo2.grid(row = 9, column = 0)

        universidad3 = tk.Label(root, text = "Universidad a la cual asistio:")
        universidad3.grid(row = 10, column = 1)

        estudios2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Area en la cual realizo sus estudios:")
        estudios2.grid(row = 11, column = 1)

        pais2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Pais en el cual realizo estos estudios:")
        pais2.grid(row = 12, column = 1)    

        #String values for the entries 

        String_4 = tk.StringVar(root)
        String_5 = tk.StringVar(root)
        String_6 = tk.StringVar(root)

        #Entries of the university 

        u4 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = String_1, width = 30)
        u1.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        u5 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = String_2, width = 30)
        u2.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        u6 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = String_3, width = 30)
        u3.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

        #Boolean value for university 

        boolean_2 = tk.BooleanVar(root)

        #Checkbuttons for the boolean value in university 
        #In case the subject has more than university title 

        titulo_2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Poseo mas de un titulo", variable = boolean_2)
        titulo_2.grid(row = 7, column = 2)

        # Submit button

        titulo_3 = tk.Button(root, text = "Agregar mas informacion", fg = 'green',activebackground = "green", activeforeground = "green")
        titulo_3.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

        submit_button_2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Enviar", fg = 'green',activebackground = "green", activeforeground = "green")
        submit_button_2.grid(row = 99, column = 99)

        root.mainloop()

#Creating the window

top = tk.Tk()

#Title of the previous window

top.title("Formato de aplicacion")

#Labels of the window
myfont = font.Font(size = 15)
Title = tk.Label(top, text = "LUNCHEVA S.A")
Title.config(fg = 'green')
Title['font'] = myfont
Title.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

greeting = tk.Label(top, text = "Por favor introduzca la informacion solicitada: ")
greeting.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
  
name = tk.Label(top, text = "Nombre")
name.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
  
email = tk.Label(top, text = "Correo Electronico")
email.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
  
phone_number = tk.Label(top, text = "Numero celular")
phone_number.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

salary = tk.Label(top, text = "Salario deseado")
salary.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

Instruccion = tk.Label(top, text ="Por favor de click sobre aquella informacion verdadera:")
Instruccion.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

Instruccion2 = tk.Label(top, text ="Usted posee: ")
Instruccion2.grid(row = 7, column = 2)

#Image of the LOGO of Luncheva 

path = "C:\\Users\Dell\\Pictures\\luncheva.jpg"

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

panel = tk.Label(top, image = img)
panel.grid(row =0, column  =0)

#Booleans for each checkbuttons 

boolean1 = tk.BooleanVar(top)
boolean2 = tk.BooleanVar(top)
boolean3 = tk.BooleanVar(top)
boolean4 = tk.BooleanVar(top)

#Checkbuttons for yes or no information 

licencia = tk.Checkbutton(top, text="Licencia de Conducir", variable = boolean1)
licencia.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

carnet = tk.Checkbutton(top, text="Carnet de manipulacion de alimentos", variable = boolean2)
carnet.grid(row = 9, column = 2)

universidad = tk.Checkbutton(top, text="Estudios universitarios", variable = boolean3)
universidad.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

identificacion = tk.Checkbutton(top, text="Identificacion vigente", variable = boolean4)
identificacion.grid(row = 11, column = 2)

#Strings of each entry

String1 = tk.StringVar(top)
String2 = tk.StringVar(top)
String3 = tk.StringVar(top)
String4 = tk.StringVar(top)

#Entries
  
e1 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable = String1, width = 30)
e1.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
e2 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable = String2, width = 30)
e2.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
e3 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable = String3, width = 30)
e3.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
e4 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable = String4, width = 30)
e4.grid(row = 5, column = 2)

#Button of the window 
  
submit = tk.Button(top, text = "Enviar", fg = 'green',activebackground = "green", activeforeground = "green", command= get_values)
submit.grid(row = 99, column = 99)

#Executing the window

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your variable "titulo" is a Checkbox at one point.  Then later you set it to some boolean value.  Then you test its truth value in the function that you say is not executing.  Perhaps when you fix that your program will behave differently.

Comment: Even the issue is fixed by the given solution, the `more_universities()` will do nothing as `titulo` is `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. You have used many `Tk()` instances at the same time.It will cause some problems.(For example,your `StringVar().get` can't get the right value).You can make the first window as a `Tk()` instance.The other windows should be `Toplevel()`.It will help.
2. In your code,

```
titulo_21 = tk.Button(master, text="Agregar mas informacion", fg='green', activebackground="green",
                              activeforeground="green", command=more_universities())
```

should be

```
titulo_21 = tk.Button(master, text="Agregar mas informacion", fg='green', activebackground="green",
                              activeforeground="green", command=more_universities)
```

About this,you can read about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)